# How to use HashSet properly Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I use hashset in my app and I'm trying to see how can I avoid leaking memory,I use as shown below by filling it out inside onActivityResult, then when the user clicks the **button** I simply process what's in there then finish the activity.

As far as I understood a memory leak isn't possible here because hashSet isn't static so as soon as the Activity finishes nothing will be pointing to the HashSet and it will be free when the GC kicks in, is this assumption correct?

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {


    HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 //process what's in the hashset 
                 //do I need to do something like hashSet.clear() 
                 //or something else like setting the hashSet to null?
                //then exit
                finish();
            }
        });


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == SOME_RETURN_CODE) {

            hashSet.add(some string);
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
is this assumption correct?
```

Yes, your assumptions are spot on. There shouldn't be any memory leaks in that activity because it doesn't hold any reference that cannot be disposed or garbage collected